# Set a transparent image as a window background while still showing the background color

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add an image as the background of a window; the image is a transparent PNG. My issue here is whenever I set the image as background it covers whatever color is under it despite being transparent, not showing my desired background color. When I compile the result is the window having the desired image as background with the transparent part being replaced by a black color instead of showing the background color I set.

My code for MainWindows.xaml is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="Eorzea_Timers.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Eorzea_Timers"
    mc:Ignorable="d"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="667" Width="375">

<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Background.png"/>
</Window.Background>

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Is it even possible to have what I want or should I just include the colored background in the image itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an Image element into the Grid:

```
<Window ... Background="White">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Background.png"/>
        <Grid>
            <!-- other elements here -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Or if for whatever reason you need to use an ImageBrush, use it as Background of the top-level Grid:

```
<Window ... Background="White">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Background.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid>
            <!-- other elements here -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is what I'd been done if it wasn't for the fact I want a search bar to be on top of the image, hence why I thought putting it as background was the best idea.

Comment: A Window can't have two different Background Brushes at the same time. You have to use an additional element. For a simple layout, just use another nested Grid on top of the Image or Rectangle.

Comment: @JustinCI from the question: "*the image is a transparent PNG*"

Comment: @nicktheone Please see the edit. The second part shows how to use two different Background Brushes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using VisualBrush, and create a shape with the desired background color and put the image on top of it.